# How many ways can we split a group of $n$ elements into groups of different sizes such that each group contains more than $1$ element

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science

let's assume $p[n]$ is the name of this partitioning method
Let's see some examples:

1. $n=3$:

   all possibilities are: $[(3,0),(2,1),(1,1,1)]$

   all cases don't meet the condition $minSize > 1$

   so $p[3]=0$.
2. $n=4$:

   all possibilities are: $[(4,0), (3,1), (2,2), (2,1,1), (1,1,1,1)]$

   only the case $(2,2)$ stands the condition $minSize>1$, 
   now, let's see how many ways can we split 4 into 2 groups of 2 elements $(2,2)=3$

   so $p[4]=(2,2)=3$
3. $n=5$:

   all possibilities are $[(5,0),(4,1),(3,1,1),(3,2),(2,2,1),(2,1,1,1),(1,1,1,1,1)]$

   only the case $(3,2)$ stands the condition $minSize>1$, $(3,2)=10$ (it starts to get harder to compute it with pen!)

   so $p[5]=(3,2)=10$

$p[6]=(4,2)+(3,3)+(2,2,2)=???$

$p[7]=(4,3)+(3,2,2)=???$

$p[8]=(6,2)+(5,3)+(4,4)+(4,2,2)+(3,3,2)+(2,2,2,2)=???$

and it get harder and harder, can you see the logic?

**EDIT**

My most serious trials so far is to try to customize [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) to solve this problem, but still have a lot of issues in formalizing it, and I am not sure if it is correct to use it, it is just my guess.

P.S: Feel free to add tags to this question, I am not sure how to tag it correctly

Comment: Why $ (3,2)=10$ and $(2,2)=3$, I don't see the link the second one must be $6$ no?

Comment: @Elaqqad: I assume you used $\binom{5}{2}=\binom{5}{3}10$, $\binom{4}{2}=6$, although it works for the $(3,2)$ but if we apply it directly to $(2,2)$ we will get half of the combinations as duplicates! try it with a piece of paper (as I did) it is an easy example and you can notice that right away

Answer (score 1):

If the objects are distinguishable then one expression (hopefully there is a better one or you can simplify this one) is
$$p[n]=-1+\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k \binom n k B_{n-k} $$ for $n\geq 2$ where $B_n$ is the nth Bell number

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number
(You're right in that they are related to the Sterling numbers; sum Sterling numbers up to get the Bell numbers.)

Count by using inclusion-exclusion with the bell numbers: $B_n$ counts the number of ways to partition a set of distinct objects. Subtract off the number of ways to have one object alone: choose the object in $\binom n 1$ ways then partition the remaining ${n-1}$ objects in $B_{n-1}$ ways. But we oversubtracted the partitions that have at least two objects alone so we add back in $\binom n 2 B_{n-2}$, then subtract off the $\binom n 3 B_{n-3}$ partitions with at least three alone, etc.
So there are $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom n k B_{n-k}$ ways to partition the set without any element alone. From above it seems you want to also exclude the case where all the elements are left together in a single group, so we subtract 1 to obtain $p[n]$ as the number of ways to partition $n$ distinct objects into at least two sets of more than 1 element. This expression agrees with your initial calculations of $p[3]=0$, $p[4]=3$, $p[5]=10$, $p[6]=40$, $p[8]=161$, $p[9]=714 \ldots$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof of the Bell number formula.

Recall the species for set partitions which is
$$\mathfrak{P}(\mathcal{U} \mathfrak{P}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z}))$$
which gives the generating function
$$G(z, u) = \exp(u(\exp(z)-1)).$$

It follows that the generating function for Bell numbers is
$$G(z) = \exp(\exp(z)-1).$$

Observe that in this problem we  are excluding sets of size one, which
gives the species
$$\mathfrak{P}(\mathfrak{P}_{\ge 2}(\mathcal{Z}))$$

which has the generating function
$$H(z) = \exp(\exp(z)-1-z) = \exp(-z) \exp(\exp(z)-1)
= \exp(-z) G(z).$$

Note that when we  multiply two exponential generating functions of
the sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ we get that
$$ A(z) B(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n \frac{z^n}{n!} 
\sum_{n\ge 0} b_n \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n\ge 0} 
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{(n-k)!} a_k b_{n-k} z^n\\
= \sum_{n\ge 0} 
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} a_k b_{n-k} \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n\ge 0} 
\left(\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a_k b_{n-k}\right)\frac{z^n}{n!}$$
i.e. the  product of  the two generating  functions is  the exponential
 generating function of $$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a_k b_{n-k}.$$

Therefore
$$n! [z^n] H(z) = n! [z^n] \exp(-z) G(z)
= \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k B_{n-k},$$
which was to be shown.

We may subtract one from this if the case of all items in a single set
is to be excluded.

The sequence
$$0, 1, 1, 4, 11, 41, 162, 715, 3425, 17722, \ldots$$
is [OEIS A000296](https://oeis.org/A000296).